# Case Insensitive Search in Xcode 15 Using Realm List

Tags: realm

I am developing a database app for storing famous quotations and I would like the users to search and the realm database. The search feature works, but it is case sensitive. I have tried the sample code solutions that comes with realm, and the search only finds upper case search strings.

I have tried the sample solutions that comes with the Realm Library, solutions from this venue, and even Apple's sample code. Here is a sample of what I have tried:

.onChange(of: filterIllus, perform: { value in
$illie.where = {$0.name.contains(value, options: .caseInsensitive)}

This does not work either.

Comment: I posted an answer to somewhat address the question but more info maybe needed as the code and query in the question doesn't have a lot of info and we don't know your coding platform. I'll refine the answer a bit when there's more clarity on what isn't working in the query. Perhaps including your model would also help.

Answer (score 0):

Given a Person class in Swift

```
class Person: Object {
   @Persisted var name = ""
}
```

and a few people objects added to Realm with names: Jay, jay, jAy and Cindy, the following code retrieves all three Jay variations

```
let results = realm.objects(PersonClass.self).where { $0.name.contains("jay", options: .caseInsensitive) }

results.forEach { person in
   print(person.name)
}
```

and the output

```
Jay
jay
jAy
```

This is similar to what's in the question but not exactly the same.

Comment: Hi Jay,  thank you so much for that excellent direction. Is the results object created with all other objects or within the .searchable modifier? That is where I am having the issue. 
Here is the Illustrations model:

Comment: @Q.Preau The results object will only contain the objects that meet the query criteria; e.g. the Cindy object would NOT be included. It's also important to understand that as objects are deleted, inserted or modified, if they match the query criteria, the results would reflect that change. e.g. if another person is added to Realm with the name of jaY, the results would automagically include that new person because they meet the query criteria. Pretty cool, huh?

Comment: I agree! State variables and ObservedResults are amazing. I was wondering: 
Where does your code fit into this:
.searchable(text: $filterIllus,
                        collection: $illie, keyPath: \.name) {
                ForEach(illie) { filterIllus in

Comment: @Q.Preau Well, it doesn't exactly fit into that piece of code as that's more of an iterator and a bit different than the code in the original question. Trying to analyze what the goal is without more context is difficult. If that's a different piece of code and you're trying to obtain a different objective, a separate question would be in order and details around what the code does and what the expected outcome is. If it's related to the question, perhaps updating the question with details would help.

Comment: thank you for your responses. I just want to use .searchable{} modifier on a RealmList in Swift for iPhones, and make the search case insensitive.

Comment: @Q.Preau To do that, you'll need to implement the OnChange modifier as well and let it perform the case-insensitive query you want. However, I believe that will negate using the Results object directly as a datasource - perhaps you'll need to utilize an array instead (need to test that theory)